# Auto approve all comments (editor)

Tags: comments, author, editor, options, comments-template

I **unchecked** both options in the `discussion` area *(so the one where they need a post to comment and administrator has to approve)*, but still, my users can't put their comments without me approving it.

Has someone a solution for this glitch? Why on earth can't they post a comment? And if they post one, the second one needs to be approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `multiple links` in a `comment` and I saw that there was an option to avoid comments that have more links than 2 in *(moderate comments)*. I set it to 0 and now it works like a charm.

Wordpress, oh Wordpress!

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard - options - discussions

Before a comment appears:

- An administrator must always approve the comment
- Comment author must fill out name and e-mail
- Comment author must have a previously approved comment

Uncheck at least 1 and 3.

Comment: That's what I stated in my post: already done that. That's not the problem brother.

Comment: If that not work, you can change your theme to default wordpress given Theme and check if it fixed, then it should be your theme code. Or you can disable plugins and check so you will know what cause the problem. Normally The above fix should work with Wordpress setup.